# Tracking Changes to Lookup When Parent is Deleted

Tags: lookup, bug, platform-bug, history-tracking

#### Question

Is it a known issue that field history tracking doesn't detect changes to a lookup field as the result of the parent object being deleted?

#### Background

We had a big data integrity issue and was able to track it down a parent object being deleted.  For example, CustomObject_*c.Account*_c, can get cleared if the related account is deleted, but it's not showing up in the history tracking.  I've reviewed the [tracking field history considerations](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US) in the help docs and it doesn't mention this limitation anywhere.  Hoping to find out if this is expected behavior before I go down the long road of filing a bug ticket with Salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive this is answer you are looking for:

```
If the parent record in a lookup relationship is deleted, the field history tracking for 
the child record does not record the deletion. For example, if a parent account is deleted, 
enter preformatted text here`the Account History related list for the child account does not show the deletion.
```

- from documentation :)

Comment: Here's the link: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Nah, I knew I forgot something :)

Comment: @ArturKępczyński thanks for the link, was surprised to find out that there is now an option for cascade deletes with regular lookup fields (it requires contacting sfdc support to enable).